# What’s the most pythonic way to iterate 2 arrays correspondingly when using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume we need to compute the value of the function with `numpy`:

[image]

I know two methods:

METHOD I:

```py
def func(b,X,Y):
  res = 0
  for i in range(len(X)):
    res += np.log(X[i] + b * Y[i])
  return res
```

METHOD II:

```py
def func(b,X,Y):
  return np.sum(np.array([np.log(X[i) + b*Y[i]) for i in range(len(X))]))
```

Are both methods (1)pythonic (2) readable (3) efficient in running time? Is there any better implementation evaluated by these three metrics?

Comment: Please define "better".

Comment: The edited portion that defines 'good' still uses opinion-based language. This needs *objective* metrics to remain open. Readability, Pythonic-ness, etc. are not objective metrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to iterate through `X` and `Y`, `numpy` can broadcast the operations natively:

```
np.log(np.array(X) + b * np.array(Y)).sum()
```

If `X` and `Y` are already `np.array`s:

```
np.log(X + b * Y).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

**The second method works great**
Because you have implemented the **vectorized** form such that the number of operations become very less compared to the method 1

Comment: The second method is not vectorized in the `numpy` sense.